# does anyone have an example of PBO + SDL2.0 + OpenGL

Tags: c++, opengl, sdl-2, pbo

Does any one have a working example of PBO's (Pixel Buffer Objects) + SDL2.0 (Simple DirectMedia Layer) + OpenGL?

The reasons is to get asynchronous GPU -> CPU downloading with GLGetPixels and thus get a performance boost.

Here's my attempt. There's no measured difference at all with use_pbo = false or true. And I've used PBOs with GLUT before on the same machine so I know that my hardware supports it.

I've looked a lot at the http://www.songho.ca/opengl/gl_pbo.html tutorial but don't see that i'm doing anything wrong.

```
bool use_pbo = true; //remember to wait a bit for fps to pick up speed

if(SDL_Init(SDL_INIT_EVENTS) != 0) throw "SDL_Init";

SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_RED_SIZE, 8);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_GREEN_SIZE, 8);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_BLUE_SIZE, 8);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_ALPHA_SIZE, 8);
SDL_GL_SetAttribute(SDL_GL_DOUBLEBUFFER, 1);

sdl_window = SDL_CreateWindow("", 10, 20, window_width, window_height, SDL_WINDOW_OPENGL | SDL_WINDOW_RESIZABLE);

sdl_gl_context = SDL_GL_CreateContext(sdl_window);
SDL_GL_MakeCurrent(sdl_window, sdl_gl_context);

vertical_sync(false);

{
    glGenBuffers(2, pbos);
    glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, pbos[0]);
    glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, pbo_width*pbo_height*4, 0, GL_STREAM_READ);

    glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, pbos[1]);
    glBufferData(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, pbo_width*pbo_height*4, 0, GL_STREAM_READ);

    glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, 0);
}

//render to default frame buffer
{
    glDrawBuffer(GL_BACK);

    glClearColor(0.1, 0.2, 0.3, 0);
    glClear(GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT);

    glEnable(GL_BLEND);
    glBlendFunc(GL_ONE, GL_ONE_MINUS_SRC_ALPHA);

    glUseProgram(simple_shader);

    glActiveTexture(GL_TEXTURE0);
    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, transparent_texture);

    glBegin(GL_TRIANGLE_STRIP);
    //textcoord, color, position
    glVertexAttrib2f(2, 0, 1); glVertexAttrib4f(1, 1, 0, 0, 1); glVertexAttrib2f(0, -1, -1); //bottom left
    glVertexAttrib2f(2, 1, 1); glVertexAttrib4f(1, 0, 1, 0, 1); glVertexAttrib2f(0, +1, -1); //bottom right
    glVertexAttrib2f(2, 0, 0); glVertexAttrib4f(1, 0, 0, 1, 1); glVertexAttrib2f(0, -1, +1); //top left
    glVertexAttrib2f(2, 1, 0); glVertexAttrib4f(1, 1, 1, 0, 1); glVertexAttrib2f(0, +1, +1); //top right
    glEnd();

    glBindTexture(GL_TEXTURE_2D, 0);

    glUseProgram(0);

    glDisable(GL_BLEND);

    while(true)
    {
        if(use_pbo)
        {
            glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, pbos[1]);
            GLvoid* map_buffer_data = glMapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, GL_READ_ONLY);

            if(map_buffer_data)
            {
                //glRasterPos2i(-1, -1); //default, left bottom
                glRasterPos2i(0, -1);
                glDrawPixels(pbo_width, pbo_height, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, map_buffer_data);
                glUnmapBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER);
            }

            glBindBuffer(GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER, 0);
        }
        else
        {       
            glRasterPos2i(0, -1); //right bottom
            glDrawPixels(pbo_width, pbo_height, GL_BGRA, GL_UNSIGNED_BYTE, t.c);
        }
    }
}

SDL_GL_SwapWindow(sdl_window);

//cycle buffers
{
    GLuint t = pbos[1];
    pbos[1] = pbos[0];
    pbos[0] = t;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Try to bind PBO to your texture

GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER for pixel data being **passed** into OpenGL GL_PIXEL_PACK_BUFFER for pixel data being **retrieved** from OpenGL

Also you should define texture image with [glTexImage2D](https://www.khronos.org/opengles/sdk/docs/man/xhtml/glTexImage2D.xml)

> If a non-zero named buffer object is bound to the GL_PIXEL_UNPACK_BUFFER target 
>               (see glBindBuffer) while a texture image is
>               specified, data is treated as a byte offset into the buffer object's data store.